# Как сделать постоянную надпись на экране?

Tags: python, pygame

Я работаю над игрой и у меня проблема. Когда я делаю проверку на проигрыш, у меня надпись мигает, то есть она выводиться и тут же пропадает, и так бесконечно. Задача в том чтобы, когда игрок проигрывает выводилась надпись и оставалась на экране.

```
if ball.bottom > MAX_Y:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 52)
        game_over = font.render('GAME OVER', 1, RED)
        screen.blit(game_over, (430, 320))
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
```

Comment: Текст появляется и исчезает произвольно, вне зависимости от нажатия клавиш? Как часто? Находится ли указанный код в другом внешнем цикле? Определен ли тикер time.Clock()?

Comment: Вне зависимости от клавиш.Каждую секунду.Нет не находиться.time.Clock определён

Comment: Мерцание обычно все же указывает на циклическую перерисовку, заливку или переопределение дисплея/поверхности. Возможны такие варианты? Как и где screen определяется?

Answer (score 0):

Короче,всё исправил.Пока не нажата кнопка ESCAPE, надпись будет на экране.

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 52)
if ball.bottom > MAX_Y:
        while True:
            game_over = font.render('GAME OVER', 1, RED)
            screen.blit(game_over, (430, 320))
            pygame.display.flip()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
```